# Sum JSON Data by using Group by in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Following data is i am getting.

```
var data =[{"Type1":2,"Type2":0,"Type3":6,"Date":"2015-01-27","Source":"Web"},
          {"Type1":2,"Type2":2,"Type3":0,"Date":"2015-02-27","Source":"Mobile"},
          {"Type1":3,"Type2":0,"Type3":7,"Date":"2015-02-27","Source":"Unknown"},
          {"Type1":4,"Type2":5,"Type3":9,"Date":"2015-02-27","Source":"Web"}]
```

I want to sum this data by doing Group by Date like this,

```
var result= 
              [{"Type1":2,"Type2":0,"Type3":6,"Date":"2015-01-27"},
              {"Type1":9,"Type2":7,"Type3":16,"Date":"2015-02-27"}]
```

For this i have written following jquery code, but its not working. Please suggest me changes.

```
    var objects = JSON.stringify(data)
      var grphDates = new Array();
            var groupedObjects = new Array();
            $.each(objects, function (ix, obj) {
                var existingObj;
                if ($.inArray(obj.Date, grphDates) >= 0) {
                    existingObj = $.grep(groupedObjects, function (o, si) { return o.Date === obj.Date; });
                    existingObj.Type1 += obj.Type1;
                    existingObj.Type2 += obj.Type2;
                    existingObj.Type3 += obj.Type3;
                  } else {
                    groupedObjects.push(obj);
                    grphDates.push(obj.Date);
                }
            });
```

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fodfxz4f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is already an array of objects so no need to do `JSON.stringify(data)`

Also take into consideration that `grep` returns an array of objects (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

This changes should do it

```
      var data =[{"Type1":2,"Type2":0,"Type3":6,"Date":"2015-01-27","Source":"Web"},
          {"Type1":2,"Type2":2,"Type3":0,"Date":"2015-02-27","Source":"Mobile"},
          {"Type1":3,"Type2":0,"Type3":7,"Date":"2015-02-27","Source":"Unknown"},
          {"Type1":4,"Type2":5,"Type3":9,"Date":"2015-02-27","Source":"Web"}];

      var grphDates = new Array();
      var groupedObjects = new Array();
      $.each(data, function (ix, obj) {
           var existingObj;
           if ($.inArray(obj.Date, grphDates) >= 0) {
                // Get index of existing object width date == obj.Date
                var index = groupedObjects.map(function(o, i) { 
                               if(o.Date == obj.Date)return i;
                               }).filter(isFinite);

                groupedObjects[index].Type1 += obj.Type1;
                groupedObjects[index].Type2 += obj.Type2;
                groupedObjects[index].Type3 += obj.Type3;
           } else {
                groupedObjects.push(obj);
                grphDates.push(obj.Date);
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [lodash's groupBy method](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy). It seems to do almost exactly what you're looking for:

```
_.groupBy(data, 'Date');
```

returns

```
{ '2015-01-27': [ 
     { Type1: 2, 
       Type2: 0, 
       Type3: 6, 
       Date: '2015-01-27', 
       Source: 'Web' 
      } 
  ],
  '2015-02-27': 
   [ { Type1: 2,
       Type2: 2,
       Type3: 0,
       Date: '2015-02-27',
       Source: 'Mobile' },
     { Type1: 3,
       Type2: 0,
       Type3: 7,
       Date: '2015-02-27',
       Source: 'Unknown' },
     { Type1: 4, 
       Type2: 5, 
       Type3: 9, 
       Date: '2015-02-27', 
       Source: 'Web' 
     } 
   ] 
}
```